Is this idiom more common among native speakers?
Someone has just posted this construction on Facebook, asking for translation into Arabic.

I'm in the driving seat, but I don't have a set of wheels.

I know the meaning of the construction and I can translate it. However, l wonder if it is more common among native speakers of English.

It's common enough to have a dictionary entries at Merriam-Webster, Cambridge, etc. Though most would say driver's not driving.

@DW256: Is the use of the two idioms " in the driver's seat and a set of wheels" in the same construction more common?

A simple google search would show you that there's not many people using that exact expression, even with driver's instead of driving. However, the meaning is clear enough and playing with idioms like this is not out of the ordinary. You can come up with similar ones pretty easily "I’ve got too many irons in the fire, and one of them just burned the house down." or "Don't put all your eggs in one basket, especially if it’s a leaking basket." or "The ball's in your court, but it's deflated." or "I hit the nail on the head, but the hammer broke."

I think it's fair to say that "I'm in the driver's seat" is a fairly common idiom, but I've never heard the whole expression used.

@DW256: l appreciate your comment.

@Peter Jennings: You're right. The whole expression hasn't appeared on Google search and it's more common with "driver's".

There are two separate idioms 1. "To be in the driver's/driving seat" -> to be in charge of, and/or responsible for, something; 2. "set of wheels" - a vehicle.

I'm not sure what I would take it mean - perhaps a metaphor: "I'm in charge, but I have nobody to organise."

Putting these two idioms together would probably be considerd a "mixed metaphor".

“More common” than what?

No, the whole sentence is not idiomatic English. I've never seen it used.
"I'm in the driver's seat" is a fairly common phrase which means "I'm in charge".
But "I don't have a set of wheels" seems to be a phrase made up by the writer. Presumably they mean they don't have anything to be in charge of, or they are unable to direct (steer) the action. Rather like a rudderless ship, you may be the captain at the helm, but you have no control over the vessel's course.

Just in case it wasn't clear, "a set of wheels" = "a vehicle" ( metonymy), and that phrase is also very commonly used in American English, especially by "muscle car" enthusiasts, both in its figurative metonymic sense of "vehicle" and also in its literal sense, four matching wheels.

Joe has a new set of wheels.  It goes from 0 to 60 in seven seconds.
Mike has a new set of wheels, and he is selling the stock wheels that came with his car.


Yes, TimR, but how does that suggest the phrase as Questioned has any place in English idiom?

It is humor.  "driver's seat" has nothing to do with cars or wheels- just means "leadership position."  By bringing in wheels which is a metaphor for a car, the writer is mocking the first idiom denoting leadership.  This figure of speech is called bathos.
